# Rebuilding a Debian package with one changed option

Tags: build, debian, libusb, udev

Can anybody tell me the **correct** way to rebuild a Debian package containing a standard Linux library, such that one individual configuration option can be changed, preferably on both current and legacy versions?

Obviously, in isolation this would simply be a case of running ./configure with the appropriate option, but I don't believe there is a succinct way of recovering the options that have been specified by a Debian package maintainer.

The best I've managed so far is to graft the required option into a 'configure ' rule in the debian/rules file. However I'm not confident that I know what I'm doing, I'm not happy with my grasp of the vast and impenetrable Debian documentation (I have no interest in packaging a new project, I only want to make one trivial change to an existing library) and I'm even less happy with the conflicting, ineffective and almost certainly outdated "advice" turned up by Google.

Rebuilding a package without modification is easy enough. There *has* to be a way of introducing a single option change.

---

As background, I was trying to recompile libusb so that I could use it in the context of a Docker container without its being dependent on udev (i.e. ./configure --disable-udev etc.). By editing debian/rules I generated a .so which was OK according to ldd, and was adequate to tell me that the problem (accessing a JTAG programmer in a Docker container) wasn't actually caused by the lack of udev etc.

However I still need to write this up for my notes (internal wiki), and I'm less than happy about the extent to which I had to grope around in an uninformed fashion.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community I was under the impression that it was adequate, If you have difficulty interpreting what I wrote please highlight specific shortcomings with enough detail that I can provide an adequate question.